# az repos pr create multiple reviewers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-repos

How can I create a pull request with multiple reviewers from he command line?

The following works:

```
az repos pr  create -s release -t master --auto-complete --reviewers "mycolleague@company.com"
```

But as soon as I specify multiple colleagues it refuses to create a pr

```
   az repos pr  create -s release -t master --auto-complete --reviewers "mycolleague@company.com anothercolleague@company.com"
   Could not resolve identity: mycolleague@company.com anothercolleague@company.com
```

If I understand [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-create) correctly, the ids should be space separated

Comment: Have you tried without the `"..."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the `"` around the list. Quote each identity if needed, but not in a single big string.

```
az repos pr create -s release -t master --auto-complete --reviewers mycolleague@company.com anothercolleague@company.com
```